# Getting NSRange of string between quotations?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a string:

> He said "hello mate" yesterday.

I want to get an NSRange from the first quotation to the last quotation. So I tried something like this:

```
NSRange openingRange = [title rangeOfString:@"\""];
NSRange closingRange = [title rangeOfString:@"\""];
NSRange textRange = NSMakeRange(openingRange.location, closingRange.location+1 - openingRange.location);
```

But I'm not sure how to make it distinguish between the first quote and the second quote. How would I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use a regular expression for this:

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"([\"])(?:\\\\\\1|.)*?\\1" options:0 error:&error];

NSRange range = [regex rangeOfFirstMatchInString:myString options:0 range:NSRangeMake(0, [myString length]];
```

Don't forget to check for errors ;)

Comment: Well it worked alright, but what on earth is this:` @"([\"])(?:\\\\\\1|.)*?\\1"` ??

Comment: @mohabitar that is a [regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) I suggest reading up on them, they are very powerful and useful.  (also, a link to Apple docs for [NSRegularExpression](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html))

Comment: Also note that it mostly looks so horrible because I had to escape some characters (every \ and ").

Comment: I'd recommend against regular expressions **in this case**. Although they are super *super* powerful, they're somewhat overkill for this scenario. Plus, they're not the most readable code. If you come back to this code sample in 6 months, you'll spend a lot of time figuring out exactly how that regex works. Never mind what will happen if someone *else* has to check/edit/refactor **your** code. Remember not to make something more complicated than it needs to be. ;-)

Comment: @mbm30075 Uhm, thats always a problem with regular expressions. They aren't exactly readable at all so you should ALWAYS add a comment explaining what they are doing.

Comment: @JustSid Which is a great argument for not using them in such a simple case! If you're parsing an email address, by all means, regex have their place. Here... not so much...

Answer (score 2):

You can always use 'rangeOfString:options:range:' for the second one (starting after the 'location' of the first one).

***Option 1***

```
- (NSRange)rangeOfQuoteInString:(NSString *)str {
    int firstMatch = [str rangeOfString:@"\""].location;
    int secondMatch = [str rangeOfString:@"\"" options:0 range:NSMakeRange(firstMatch + 1, [str length] - firstMatch - 1)].location;
    return NSMakeRange(firstMatch, secondMatch + 1 - firstMatch);
}
```

I hope this is right. Done on my phone at dinner. ;-)

One other thing, though, since range of string likely does a similar implementation, why not iterate the 'char' values in the string and look for matches #1 & #2? Could be as fast or faster.

***Option 2***

```
- (NSRange)rangeOfQuoteInString:(NSString *)str {
    int firstMatch = -1;
    int secondMatch = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < [str length]; i = i + 1) {
        unichar c = [str characterAtIndex:i];
        if (c == '"') {
            if (firstMatch == -1) {
                firstMatch = i;
            } else {
                secondMatch = i;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if (firstMatch == -1 || secondMatch == -1) {
        // No full quote was found
        return NSMakeRange(NSNotFound, 0);
    } else {
        return NSMakeRange(firstMatch, secondMatch + 1 - firstMatch);
    }
}
```

Comment: Which method are you asking about?

Comment: @mbm30075 Your second version is prone to encoding issues (and `characterAtIndex:` returns unichar, not char!)

Comment: @JustSid How would you fix it? And don't say "use regex"! ;-)

Comment: @mbm30075 With a regex obviously :P Jk, I would probably try to get a version of the string with a known encoding, eg. with `UTF8String` or similar and then use this instead.